# Oozie commandline filters

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

oozie job -info $coordinator

the command gives you the details of workflows belong to the coordinator, print their ID, status, created time and nominal time.

I'm trying to print the workflows of the oozie coordinator which are executed after a specific date.

As per their documentation,

```
-filter <arg>         <key><comparator><value>[;<key><comparator><value>]*
                            (All Coordinator actions satisfying the filters will be retrieved).
                            key: status or nominal time
                            comparator: =, !=, <, <=, >, >=. = is used as OR and others as AND
                            status: values are valid status like SUCCEEDED, KILLED etc. Only = and != apply for status.
                            nominaltime: time of format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'
```

From this, it's understandable that status key supports only "=" or "!=" whereas nominal time key supports all comparators.

But when I try to use it, I'm getting below error.

```
[hadoop@xx ~]$ oozie job -info $coord -filter status nominalTime>2018-09-01'T'08:00'Z'
Error: E0421 : E0421: Invalid job filter [nominalTime], filter should be of format <key><comparator><value> pairs
```

The same command works if I put "=" or "!=" but throws an error if you use other comparators. (>,<,>=,<=)

Kindly suggest how to fix this or any other alternatives for this use case.

Comment: **>** is trapped by the shell interpreter and means _" redirect StdOut to that file"_ !!! Put the whole argument between double quotes.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot. It works fine now after putting > in double quotes. Whole argument in double quotes not working.

Answer (score 0):

-filter 'nominaltime>2019-11-01T01:00Z'